# PIG output query for selecting particular value based on groupby clause

Tags: apache-pig

I have a table with data like:

```
cust_id, acct_no, ind
123111,  1233,     Y
123111,  2311,     N
222111,  1112,     N
222111,  2111,     N
```

I have to get output as `cust_id, 1` (a binary indicator if any of the acct under that customer is Y)

so from the above table I have to get below output.

```
123111    1
222111    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Load data and foreach row check whether the ind value is 'Y' then return 1 for that row else return 0.Finally distinct the rows.

**EDIT:**

```
--A = LOAD 'data.txt' USING PigStorage(',') as (cust_id:int,acct_no:int,ind:chararray);
-- Note: I am only loading two columns

A = LOAD 'data.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (id:int,ind:chararray);
B1 = FILTER A BY (ind == 'Y');
B2 = FILTER A BY (ind == 'N');
B3 = DISTINCT B2;
C = JOIN B3 BY id LEFT OUTER,B1 by id;
D = FOREACH C GENERATE B3::id as id,(B1::ind== 'Y'? 1 : 0) as ind;
E = FOREACH D GENERATE id,((ind IS NULL) ? 0 : ind);
DUMP E;
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Here is an example with a larger dataset

**INPUT**

```
123111,Y
123111,N
222111,N
222111,N
333111,Y
333111,N
444111,Y
444111,N
555111,N
555111,N
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: If data is exactly like what OP has mentioned, then either delimiter should contain white space or you need to call trim inside foreach. Latter seems to be the easier one.

Comment: I dont think i will get desired output bcoz as per the above logic i will get the B as follow.                                                                                                         123111        1                                                                                               123111        0                                                                                                 so after distinct we cant ensure that i will get only 1 i mean if 1st customer is 0 then i may get output as 0 rite.

Comment: basically my intention here is if any  account under customer having indicator as Y then output will be---> customer ,1

Comment: @Sandeep You are correct, I've edited the answer and ran a few tests.Check it out.

Comment: Thanks inquisitive